# Write data to excel using Late binding comma-separated number strings are converted to number format

Tags: c#, excel

I have a property named `Year` and its value can selected multiple like 2017, 2016, but when we write this value to excel it automatically converted to Number format like 201,62,017.

So I need to set the cell format to Text before writing the value.

I need the solution using Late Binding. I only find the below code:

```
oRange.GetType().InvokeMember("NumberFormat", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oRange, oParams);
```

This is for set the range as NumberFormat, Right?

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be correct, and to set Text cell format it should be called like this:

```
oRange.GetType().InvokeMember("NumberFormat", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oRange, new object[] {"@"});
```